# Hyperlinks in References not linking properly

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, links, back-referencing

When making my document, in the bibliography at the end of each item there is a hyperlink to the page where the item was cited. But when I make the preamble in roman numbers the TOC may work fine, but not the bibliography. When clicking the page where cited, the link goes up to the preamble. Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 


\usepackage[spanish] {babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[pdftex, plainpages=false, hypertexnames=false, pdfpagelabels=true,
hyperindex=true, linktocpage, pagebackref=true, pdfa=true]{hyperref}    
\usepackage{titlesec}           
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures 
\listoftables

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
here comes my text

\chapter{Conclusion}
\cite{one}

\phantomsection % To make hyperref link in TOC work correctly
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname} % puts entry
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{one}
Me, ``My project,'' October 2015.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `hypertexnames=false` or set it to `true`. `hyperref`'s anchor names usually consists of the counter name and the counter value (like `\the<counter>`). But the latter can sometimes contain weird stuff or is not unique. Then `\theH<counter>` should be defined to contain the counter value part for the anchor names. `hypertexnames=false` is an emergency option, which uses the values of a unique counter, without relation to the referenced counter. Things like page references of the index or back references will not work longer.